# favicon.ico 503 (Service Unavailable)

Tags: openshift

When running a GET request for the root url of my deployment for the designated route, I get an HTTP Status 503 for /favicon.ico

http://blog-xyz-blog.1234.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/favicon.ico <- amended URL for privacy..

I then rsh onto the pod and curl the localhost url for the root url, and I get an HTTP 200, and same when I curl the /favicon.ico

I added the link to my index.html  section, and the same issue occurring.

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Thanks

Comment: Ive noticed that the route is constantly stating "The route is not accepting traffic yet because it has not been admitted by a router." and the progress spinner is showing.

Comment: In fact Im sure this relates to no router being created, Im trying to create one but the error messages encountered, arent very helpful -> "User "xyz@hotmail.com" cannot list all securitycontextconstraints in the cluster"